# Mpr121 multiple using breakout

Tags: arduino-mega

I try more solution but there are not working. i use adafruit mpr121 lib, sparkfuns solution but there are not working. Some solutions say, cut the addr socket but i am not understand. maybe you show this solutions breakout, i try my code.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the wording of your question is very poor, however I think you are asking how to use multiple MPR121 devices on an Arduino?

According to the Sparkfun website you can change the I2C address from the default of 0x5A to one of four other addresses by cutting the jumpers on the back and connecting it to one of the other pins:

- ADDR > GND  = 0x5A (default)
- ADDR > 3.3V = 0x5B
- ADDR > SDA  = 0x5C
- ADDR > SCL  = 0x5D

I would also recommend using the [Bare Conductive](https://github.com/BareConductive/mpr121) libraries rather than Sparkfun/Adafruit as they are more user friendly.